# Mongo and creating a new database in dev with a reduced size

Tags: mongodb

I use the below to create a new database in mongo

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db2/
```

When I start mongo e.g.

```
mongod --port 27019 --dbpath /data/db2 --replSet rtb/test:27017 --rest
```

Mongo creates a 3 gig file.  I am in dev and to reduce the size to e.g. 100 Megs.  How to I do that?

Comment: Can you provide the output of find in the /data/db2 directory so we can see what files exist, and how big they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB will pre-allocate data files. when it starts running. By default a new database will contain the following files (*where `test` is the name of the DB*)

- `test.ns` (16MB)
- `test.0` (16MB)
- `test.1` (32MB)

As more files are needed, the pattern continues: 64MB, 128MB, 256MB, 1024MB, 2048MB. After 2GB, each new file will be 2GB.

In your case, you are running a **replica set**. Replica Sets require a database called `local`. This database contains the `oplog` which is used replication. The `oplog` is a [capped collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections).

The capped collection is a special collection which must be pre-allocated. In your case it is likely defaulting to about 3GB.

You can control the size of the `local` database using the [`--oplogSize` parameter](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters).

If you want to keep your local copy small you can also use the `--smallfiles` option which will slow down the speed of pre-allocation.